# Python3 cannot import gi

Tags: 14.04, python3, pygtk

I was attempting to run an indicator for pushbullet without avail. I attempted to run through the terminal when I noticed python3 can not import gi

```
bin > python3 pushbullet-indicator
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "pushbullet-indicator", line 26, in <module>
 import gi
 ImportError: No module named 'gi'
bin >
```

Attempting a manual import.

```
~ > python3
Python 3.4.1 (default, Sep 27 2014, 09:00:29) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'gi'
>>>
```

but for some reason Python2 can?

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>>
```

I have Anaconda installed. I'm attempting to import gi on the system's install of python3. I hope that is the correct terminology. python3-gi is installed.

Even stranger is that I can run indicator-cpufreq

Do you guys have any ideas or recommendations? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

python packages installed system-wide may not be available for python versions installed in anaconda directories.

Try instead to load your script using the full path to the system interpreter:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>>
```

Comment: This works too.

Answer (score 1):

Some packages like `gi` does not exist in the conda environment directory after installation but the system's Python directory. You could use `conda-forge` to install the package so that could run it directly from your conda Python 3 environment.

```bsh
conda install -c conda-forge pygobject
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.   If you're using Anaconda, don't install Python packages directly, install them into Anaconda and use that at all times.   Otherwise you can end up in a right mess.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your conda environment.  I told it to add to bashrc, but then took the environment variable modification and broke it out to a script 'enable_conda' in ~/bin.

See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/588064/if-you-install-anaconda-how-can-you-inactivate-the-anaconda-environment

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand. Anaconda added ~/anaconda/bin to my path. grepping for python, it appears only the following commands would be over written.

    bin > ls | grep python
    activate-global-python-argcomplete 
    ipython
    ipython2
    python
    python2
    python2.7
    python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
    python-config
    register-python-argcomplete
    bin > ]^C
    bin >

Comment: Anaconda works by overriding your global python environment and using only the share in your ~/Anaconda subfolders.  gir is notoriously hard to build/install in a venv...  so, to use your global python env, you have to disable that env mangling anaconda puts in your bashrc.